# Javascript not sending post parameters in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, post

I have the following js function that sends a post request back to the main index page. This script is working in Chrome but is not sending any parameters in firefox while still posting back to the page. I am verifying this via the network tab after inspecting the page in firefox.

```
function addDrive(ans){
    $.post("index.php", {add_drive: ans });
    location.reload();
}
```

This function is called via a onClick on a button I have placed on my page:

```
<button onClick="addDrive('y')">Add Drive</button>
```

I have used similar functions in the past that have worked for both firefox and chrome and I just cant figure out why this does not work in firefox.

Comment: You're doing a reload. that means anything the page is doing can/will get interrupted by the "new" page being loaded, killing your ajax request.

Comment: Did you try `$.post("index.php", {add_drive: ans }).done(function() { location.reload() });`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be doing something like this :

```
function addDrive(ans) {
  $.post("index.php", {add_drive: ans}).then(function() {
    location.reload();
  });
}
```

This would ensure that you reload the page only after successfully finishing the post request. You could also provide a `success` handler instead if you prefer that instead of using this promises API. You could also do the same in an `always` handler to ensure it reloads the page even if the request fails but that would be subjective to your requirements.

However, I would argue that this doesn't look like good practice at all, if you have to reload the page you could just have a form and post that instead of trying to post using the jquery handler. You could do something like `form.submit()` in javascript and that would submit the form and it would submit the data in the form by a post request as long as the method on the form is set to 'POST', that way you don't have to reload the page manually and you can do that from the server end.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload your page after successful post:

```
$.post("index.php", {add_drive: ans}).done(function( data ) {
    location.reload();
});
```